# Do the top and bottom insets of a UIButton not work with more than 2 lines?

Tags: ios, swift

Do the top and bottom insets of a UIButton not work with more than 2 lines?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: @fishinear because of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299090/uibutton-background-height-does-not-wrap-text-title-swift

Comment: That question already has an answer. If that does not answer your question, then you have to rephrase it, and be a LOT more specific on what is not working.