# UIButton background height does not wrap text (title) - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

The height of the UIButton background (white in the picture below) does not fully wrap its text (the title). I even try to set the inset (content), but this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try set background image with resizable image:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeBackgroundImage"];
image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(image.size.height / 2, image.size.width / 2, image.size.height / 2, image.size.width / 2) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
[self setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Swift:

```
var image = UIImage(named: "SomeImageName")!;
image = image.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(image.size.height / 2.0, image.size.width / 2.0, image.size.height / 2.0, image.size.width / 2.0), resizingMode: .Stretch)
button.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: @Vitality Gozhenko I am writing this in Swift. What would the code look like then? Thank you.